# Consuming Secure RESTful API

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I need to build an application that consumes a RESTful API from an external company. The data that I am consuming is sensitive, so it obviously will need HTTPS.

My problem is that I was able to read the information from the outside company without configuring any sort of SSL certificate. I did not have to do any sort of encryption/decryption in my code.

The only thing I have that would lead me to believe that the data is secure is that the RESTful call only works with `https` in the URL and not `http`.

I am using Spring RestTemplate to consume the web services as shown below:

```
List<Info> getInfo(Map<String, Object> urlParamMap, HttpSession httpSession){
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(httpSession.getHttpHeaders());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpSession.getMessageConverterList());

    ResponseEntity<JsonData> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("https://outsideOrg.com/{parameter}, HttpMethod.GET, request, JsonData.class, urlParamMap);

    List<Info> infoList = responseEntity.getBody().getInfoList();

    return infoList;
}
```

This is some of my http set up, including authorization and some deserialization settings:

```
public class HttpSession {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HttpSession.class);

    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverterList;

    HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() {
        return httpHeaders;
    }

    void setHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        this.httpHeaders = httpHeaders;
    }

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverterList() {
        return messageConverterList;
    }

    void setMessageConverterList(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverterList) {
        this.messageConverterList = messageConverterList;
    }

    void createHeaders(){
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();  
        try {
            File xmlFile = new File("C:/Users/User/docs/RestAuth.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

            String username = document.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0).getTextContent();
            String password = document.getElementsByTagName("password").item(0).getTextContent(); 

            String authorization = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] encodedAuthorization = Base64.encodeBase64(authorization.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));   
            String authorizationHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuthorization);

            httpHeaders.set("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
            httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        }catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            log.error("There was an error setting the credentials.", e);
        }
        this.httpHeaders = httpHeaders;
    }      

    void setupMessageConverters(){
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverterList = new ArrayList<>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        messageConverterList.add(messageConverter);

        this.messageConverterList = messageConverterList;
    }
```

I am confused as to what all I would need to do include an SSL certificate, if one is needed, and encrypt/decrypt the data.  Is it a problem that the external site is returning the information seemingly unencrypted without asking for an SSL certificate?

I am new to SSL and relatively new to REST in general, so forgive my ignorance on this topic. Any help that can be offered or resources I can be directed towards would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JRE contains a trust store with the certificates of certain public CAs. If the company uses a certificate, which is signed by one of the trusted CAs, the JRE can establish the SSL connection without any further configuration. Otherwise you would get an error message, that the certificate is not trusted.

If you specify an HTTPS url, the JRE will always try to setup an encrypted connection. If it doesn't work, you get an exception.

Comment: To add on, I have another question: Since I don't do any configuring an SSL certificate, does that mean the server I am getting the information from isn't checking for certificates? My organization should be the only one getting this information, so there is a problem I will need to take up with the external organization if they are just giving out the info to anyone who might happen to know the URL and username/password.

Comment: With SSL the server doesn't check any certificate, your client does. Your server offers a certificate, and the client checks if it is trusted. In your case it is. So the connection is encrypted. Another point is authentication. You use usernames and password, which is one sort of authentication. You also can use client certificates, but then you have to do some configuration. Though i don't see the problem which you have with username and password here. Of course, if someone has a username and password, he gets access to that API, that's the whole point of username and passwords.

Comment: That's why you have to keep the credentials as a secret. If you give them away to other people, that's your responsibility then.